# JqGrid pager loads same data in every page

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid

Data loaded as I expected. Pages counted too. But when I change the page number same data appears.

Here is the jQgird code:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "classes/classesController.php",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        postData: {method:"getLogsList"},
        colNames: ["Id","Ip", "Hostname", "Log", "Ημ/νια"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "log_id", index:"log_id", width: 100, sortable:false, hidden:true},
            { name: "ip", index: "ip", width: 130, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']} },
            { name: "hostname", index:"hostname", width: 180 , searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']}},
            { name: "log", index:"log", width: 180, align: "right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']}},
            { name: "date", index:"date", width: 180, align: "right", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']}}
        ],
        jsonReader: { root: "rows", page: "page", total: "total", records: "records", repeatitems: true, cell: "cell",  id: "id",},
        caption: "Logs",
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        height: 'auto',
        shrinkToFit: false,
        rowNum:2,
        pager: '#gridpager'
    });
```

and here the php part :

```
init_mysql();

        $response = new stdClass();


        // Getting pages number (for jqGrid pager)

        if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM logs");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $count = $row['count']; 

        if( $count >0 ) {
            $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
        } else {
            $total_pages = 0;
        }

        if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
        $start = $limit*$page - $limit;

        $response->page = $page;
        $response->total = $total_pages;
        $response->records = $count;


        // Getting data for jqGrid table

        $data =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY log_id DESC");
        $i = 0;

        if(mysql_num_rows($data))
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
            { 

                $response->rows[$i]['id']=$i+1; 

                $response->rows[$i]['cell']=array('log_id'=>$row['log_id'],'ip'=>$row['ip'],'hostname'=>$row['host'],'log'=>$row['input'],'date'=>$row['date']);

                $i++;
            }   
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
```

Why this happens ? As I saw in the request all works fine.
page one became page 2 and so on..

```
method=getLogsList&_search=false&nd=1371379260922&rows=33&page=2&sidx=&sord=asc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer would be: you should add `loadonce: true` option to fix the problem or change your server code to implement server side paging.

jqGrid support two styles of division of labor between the server and the client side. Old versions of jqGrid (before version 3.7) had support only server side paging, sorting and filtering of data. You don't use `loadonce: true` option, so you should follow the agreement:

- jqGrid send to the server (to `url`) parameters `rows`, `page`, `sidx` and `sord`. For example `sidx=ip`, `sord=asc`, `rows=10`, `page=2`. It means that the server have to sort the full dataset by `ip` column in `ASC` order and returns back **only the second page** (`page=2`) of the data. The page size are defined by `rows` parameter. If `rows=10` then one have to skip the first 10 items and return the next 10 items (or less if the total number of the items are less then 20). The exact SQL statement depends on the SQL server which you use. One can use `LIMIT`, `TOP` and so on constructions. The returned data should includes `records` - the total number of *items*, `total` - the number of *pages* calculated based on tne page size `rows`. The `page` of the server response is optional. Typically it's the same page number which was requested, but in general the server can detect the changing of total number of items and returns *another* page. For example if the user requested the page 100 and one have only 7 pages then the server can detect the problem and returns the past page number 7. In the case the property `page` of the server response should be set to 7 - the number of returned page.

If you need display the dataset in the grid which is not so large (for example some hundred items) then it could be more effective to use `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid. In the case the server should **just sort the data and returns all sorted items**. After the first loading the `datatype` option of the grid will be automatically changed to `"local"`. jqGrid displays only the first page of returned data, but it hold *all returned items*. The later sorting, paging and searching/filtering will be implemented *locally* without any communication with the server. Because JavaScript engine of modern web browsers are very quickly, then paging of relatively large set of data could be much quickly as sending of requests to the server.

Comment: I see. You are right.  If i have set it true i filtering toolbar doesn't  work as i expected because it doesn't send any request in server. Now i turned it to false (the loadonce) but can you send some sample code to see how i have to solve this ? Thank you.

Comment: @F.N: If you use `loadonce: true` you do can use filtering because jqGrid do this for you **locally**. You have to think only about the options of `filterToolbar`, about `colModel` options which corresponds your data, the order of items in `sopt` of `searchoptions` could be very important. I can't send you any PHP code because I use another language on the server side.

Comment: Hmmm ok i add to my `colModel` the `searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']}` which means `contains` and now works. I have one more question. If i add new data in MYSQL server i have to run this code ? `$('#grid').trigger("reloadGrid");`

Comment: @F.N: One uses typically `navGrid` which add Refresh button. One reset `datatype` to `"json"` *before* reloading. If you don't need editing of data you can use `$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#gridpager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false, refreshstate: "current",  beforeRefresh: function () { $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json"}); }});`

Comment: a) No i need to edit data of the grid. So what you suggest me  b) Also something more about filtering. Is there any way to make it filter with out take in count if the letters are in upper or lower case ?

Comment: @F.N: To make case insensitive local filtering you should use `ignoreCase: true` option of jqGrid. Editing of data is independent from another questions. I wrote about editing only because of options of `navGrid`. Your questions from comments are far from your original question which I answered. Do you have questions to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Finally i found the answer. The problem was the loadonce. And it has to be set true

`loadonce: true`